# Not sure how to solve...

Tags: complex-analysis

Solve for 
$$ z= x+iy $$
$$ 5z+iz^*=9z-3iz^*+6i $$
where $z^*$ is $z$ conjugate.  I don't really understand what the problem here is asking for and am thoroughly confused as this is not covered in my materials. I have tried to just plug in the $z$ into the question and got
$$ 5x+5iy+ix+y=9x+9iy-3ix-3y+6i $$ 
but wasn't sure what to solve for...

edit: I tried to go further by only doing the reals alone and imaginaries by themselves
$$ 5x+y=9x-3y $$
and
$$ 5iy+ix=9iy-3ix+6i $$
Now I'm actually stuck and im not sure how to solve from here.

So I ended up using substitution to solve and i got that there is no solution.

Comment: Welcome to the forums :). "Solve" and "Find the solution to" with respect to equations ALWAYS implies to find the pronumeral. In this case, that is $z$. In other words, they want you find the value of $z$ which is a complex number in the form of $x+iy$ such that it satisfies the equation above. For example if a question says solve $x + 1 = 7$, you have to find the value of $x$.

Comment: Group the real and imaginary parts before you do anything.

Comment: You've made a number of errors in your simplification. Correct those, and then equate real and imaginary parts on each side--that will give you a system of two equations in two unknowns to solve.

Comment: The real portion on the left  must equal the real portion on the right and similarly for complex parts. Solving those two equations should give you the answer.

Comment: @MPW oops I made an error typing the 9iy. I had it written down but mistyped. are there any other mistakes that I have missed?

Comment: Use some [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so your post is easier to read.

Comment: Is it that bad? Im not too familiar on how to use mathjax so I tried to make it look as clean as i could with the basic formatting.

Comment: No it's not that bad, but if you want a better response from the community then you should learn it.